# removing trailing whitespaces

Tags: python, pyparsing

By default pyparsing remove only leading whitespaces.

so parsing this

```
'between ( 1, map(  v7 , 2  ) )'
```

gives me

```
['between', [['1'], ['map', [['v7 '], ['2  ']]]]]
```

instead of

```
['between', [['1'], ['map', [['v7'], ['2']]]]]
```

but how to remove trailing whitespaces using pyparsing ?

the code is:

```
from pyparsing import Forward, Word, alphas, alphanums, nums, Literal, Group, delimitedList, Optional
lparen = Literal("(").suppress()
rparen = Literal(")").suppress()
name = Optional(Word(alphanums + '_ ', alphanums + '_ '))
functor = Word(alphas, alphanums)
integer  = Word( nums )
expression = Forward()
arg =  Group(expression) |name | integer 
args = delimitedList(arg)
expression << ((functor + lparen + args + rparen) | name)

print( expression.parseString("between ( 1, map(  v7 , 2  ) )"))
>>> ['between', ['1'], ['map', ['v7 '], ['2  ']]]
```

pyparsing.**version** = '2.0.1' and python3.

At this moment I use additional outer functions before and after parse to prapare and fix data.

Comment: Can you include the parser code that you used to get this? pyparsing will only include spaces in what is matched if you tell it to.

Comment: At some point you must have told pyparsing to keep whitespace. By default, it would have removed all whitespace and tokenized it for you. As Paul said, we can't help you unless you post your grammar.

Comment: Running your posted code prints `['between', ['1'], ['map', ['v7'], ['2']]]` - no trailing spaces.

Comment: thanks Paul - I reedit code and now I see that was `name = Optional(Word(alphanums + '_ ', alphanums + '_ '))` instead of `name = Optional(Word(alphanums + '_ '))`.
space in bodyChars of Word is not stripped.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has two occurrences of `alphanums + '_ '` -- changing them both to `alphanums + '_'` (removing the space) achieves what you're describing.

```
from pyparsing import Forward, Word, alphas, alphanums, nums, Literal, Group, delimitedList, Optional

lparen = Literal("(").suppress()
rparen = Literal(")").suppress()
name = Optional(Word(alphanums + '_', alphanums + '_'))
functor = Word(alphas, alphanums)
integer = Word(nums)
expression = Forward()
arg = Group(expression) | name | integer 
args = delimitedList(arg)
expression << ((functor + lparen + args + rparen) | name)

print( expression.parseString("between ( 1, map(  v7 , 2  ) )"))
```

Prints:

```
['between', ['1'], ['map', ['v7'], ['2']]]
```

I'm not sure if you were able to reach this conclusion from the comments, but it looks like that's what [Paul McGuire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165216/paul-mcguire) was describing. That is to say, pyparsing only included spaces in what was matched because `alphanums + '_ '` included a space in what was matched.